# step by step solr katta integration

Tags: solr, katta

I am trying to find the solr and katta integration.

But didn't find any good tutorial for the same.
Could you please give me step by step integration of katta and solr.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Katta integration with Solr is still very much in development. See this wiki page for additional details in this effort: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/KattaIntegration

What features of Solr do you need to have that Katta doesn't provide out of the box?

Comment: Looks like development activities for such an integration were abandoned:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1395
says:
"With Cloudera Search and Blur being available, plus SolrCloud, I think we can't close this as Won't Fix"